# How do I terminate a shell program through python

Tags: python

Let's say I do somthing like this:

```py
import os
os.system('java some_program.jar')
```

Is there a way to stop the execution of that program through python?

**My situation:**
I have a program in java that does some stuff and inserts data into a .csv file and I need to run it through python (because I'm using python for handeling the data in the .csv file) but the program itself doesn't stop by itself so i need a way to stop it manually once it inserts the data into the .csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `os.system`.

Instead, use `p = subprocess.Popen(...)`. Then simply call `p.kill()`.

Also, your Java program should be updated to exit when it sees EOF on stdin.

Answer (score -1):

You could try having the java program echo to console or something that it is finished writing to the CSV file using the subprocesses library and it's check_output function. And when that is done, use something like this: `os.system("taskkill /im some_program.jar")` to kill off the program.